# Manually clean database cache

Tags: database, cache

Is it possible to manually clean the database caches for templates? Doing it from the CP becomes stuck.

Comment: I'd be more interested in why it's getting stuck and how we can fix it from sticking!

Comment: in my case the cache had ballooned to immense proportions and the database process timed out when trying to clean it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three database tables that Craft uses to manage template caches:

```
craft_templatecachecriteria
craft_templatecacheelements
craft_templatecaches
```

You can visit each of those tables remove any records in them directly.

Answer (score 4):

This does not target the database cache specifically but I wrote this simple plugin to clear all caches from outside of the control panel.

https://github.com/themccallister/craft.cache-clear

Would that work for you?